# Extracting installer. ....Extraction failed. No space left on

Tags: linux, installation

I get this installation issue:

```
Wolfram Mathematica 12.1.1 for LINUX Installer Archive

Verifying archive integrity. 
Extracting installer. ....Extraction failed. No space left on .15477
Removing temporary files.
```

I have almost 100 GB of free space. Setting a local temporary directory, `TMPDIR=tmp`, doesn't change things, either, as ".15477" is put in the current working directory.

Answer (score 2):

This was caused by having a custom `$TAR_OPTIONS` set. `unset $TAR_OPTIONS` fixed the issue.